# How to get an output on adb shell input keyevent?

Tags: android, adb

I am currently stuck on this problem. I use "adb shell input keyevent" to send various event keys to an virtualized android device.
I don't get any output at all using this method, not even if i try obviously wrong or incomplete keyevents.
Is there a possibility to verify, that the keyevent has been properly sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output of these keyevents using `adb shell uiautomator events`